# How to increment the numbers in mysql with a character prefix which is fixed

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table where I will get a column like this

```
c00001
c00002
c00003
c00004
```

and so on.

I use `xampp` `mysql` but any SQL server command would be helpful. This means I want to increment this `id` followed by a `varchar`.

Comment: sql server and mysql both are different

Comment: Please clarify your question and use proper formatting.

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can't accomplish this in MySQL using triggers or generated columns because neither of those can access an auto-increment column value.

Your best bet may we to use a view to build the strings you want based on the auto-increment values.

Try something like this:

```
create or replace view v_your_table as 
  select *,
    concat('c',lpad(id,5,'0')) as str_id 
  from your_table;
```

Comment: can you please give me the code
create table so (
 id int(3) unsigned zerofill not null auto_increment primary key,
 name varchar(30) not null
);

insert into so set name = 'John';
insert into so set name = 'Mark';

select concat('LHPL', id) as id, name from so;
i have found this on this site . but i actually want the prefix in my db not to change the view only